# Adding Foreign key relationships in SQL server using T-SQL fails

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, t-sql, foreign-keys

I've been trying to create a table(name - "UserItem") with foreign keys from two previously created tables(names - "EndUser" , "Item") but i keep getting the error

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 9
>   Incorrect syntax near 'GO'.

The code syntax for creating the Table is

```
CREATE TABLE UserItem (
userID int   NOT NULL,    
itemName varchar(25) NOT NULL,   
CONSTRAINT FK_uid FOREIGN KEY (userID) REFERENCES EndUser (userID), 
CONSTRAINT FK_iname FOREIGN KEY (itemName) REFERENCES Item (itemName)  
ON DELETE CASCADE    
ON UPDATE CASCADE   
)GO
```

The syntax for the two previously created Tables are as follows,

```
CREATE TABLE EndUser(    
userID int PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,     
userName varchar(25) NOT NULL,    
userPW varchar(8) NOT NULL      
)GO 


CREATE TABLE Item(    
itemName varchar(25) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,    
tag1 varchar(20) NOT NULL,     
tag2 varchar(20) NOT NULL,     
tag3 varchar(20) NOT NULL,    
)GO
```

Im using Visual studio 2015 if that helps in any way.

Comment: `Go` should be on a separate line of its own,

Comment: try putting GO on the next line. But also, are you really sure you want cascade delete ? Have you really thought about that ? Do you know what the consequences are ?

Comment: Thanks guys putting GO on a different line Worked im new to T-SQL and 
@GuidoG im following the examples in the Documentation and cascade Delete and cascade Update arnt required i was blindly following the sample code in the documentation. again thanks a lot for the help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just by removing GO it will work

Comment: Thank you  it also works by removing the "GO" statement.
adding the "GO" statement on a different line works too as @DhruvJoshi   mentioned so both are solutions for my question. 
for anyone else who is equally lost like me and jumped straight into coding without properly reading the documentations and tutorials please refer these links   [about go](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/sql-server-utilities-statements-go) and
[a quick tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/t_sql/index.htm)  to quickly get an overview about t-sql. it saves a lot of time :)